# [NSDate descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]] leak?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, nsdate, instruments

[image]Using instruments I found a strange problem regarding memory leaks. My app has a log mechanism which record events through the app and the whole communication with the server(request-response). Each event object that is been wrote has a timestamp. This timestamp is get as follows:

```
[NSDate descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]]
```

Using instruments, I saw that descriptionWithLocale cause leaks.

Below is the code:

```
-(id)initEvent:(NSString*)eventStr details:(NSString*)detailsStr{
     eventString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:eventStr];
     detailsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:detailsStr];
     date =[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
     NSDate* currentDate = [NSDate date];    
     NSString *dateDescStr = [currentDate descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
      [date appendString:dateDescStr];  

    return [super init];
```

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's `descriptionWithLocale` that's causing your memory leak? You're not using the property accessor/mutator to set your class properties and you're releasing them in a method other than your `dealloc` method, which is going to cause issues. At the least, you're violating the basic memory management rules by allocating `eventString`, `detailsString`, and `date` in `initEvent` (which is then the owner, because you don't use a property accessor/mutator) and releasing them in the `eventDictionary` method, which is not the owner.

I would start by trying the following (assuming all your properties have the `retain` attribute):

```
-(id)initEvent:(NSString*)eventStr details:(NSString*)detailsStr{
     this.eventString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:eventStr];
     this.detailsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:detailsStr];
     this.date =[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
     NSDate* currentDate = [NSDate date];    
     NSString *dateDescStr = [currentDate descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
      [date appendString:dateDescStr];  
     [eventString release];
     [detailsString release];
     [date release];

    return [super init];
}
```

Also remove your release calls from eventDictionary and add them to the dealloc method, as per the standard memory management pattern.

Give that a try and see if it helps. Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your solution. It works great. Indeed not descriptionWithLocale was the cause of the leak, but my own memory rule implementation (was 1 year ago :( ). Strange that instruments was pointing out to that method call.... See how my class looks now:

```
@implementation EventItem
@synthesize eventString, detailsString, date;


-(id)initEvent:(NSString*)eventStr details:(NSString*)detailsStr{

    if((self = [super init])){
      self.eventString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:eventStr];
      self.detailsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:detailsStr];
      self.date =[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
      NSDate* currentDate = [NSDate date];    
      NSString *dateDescStr = [currentDate descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
      [date appendString:dateDescStr];      
      [eventString release];
      [detailsString release];
      [date release];
  }

  return self;
}

-(NSMutableDictionary*)eventDictionary{
    if(!dictionary)
       dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    else
        return dictionary;

   [dictionary setObject:self.date forKey:@"Event"];
   [dictionary setObject:self.date forKey:@"Date"];
   [dictionary setObject:self.detailsString forKey:@"Details"];
   [dictionary setObject:self.eventString forKey:@"EventDescription"];

   return [dictionary autorelease];
 }

-(void)dealloc{     
    // NSLog(@"dealloc called in EventItem");

   [eventString release];
   [detailsString release];
   [date release];

   [super dealloc]; 
}


@end
```

Now, another problem that i have is regarding to some image loaded via "loadWithContentsOfFile:"

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = OC_CELL_HEIGHT;
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIImage* backgroundImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TableBg" ofType:@"png"]];
    UIImageView* background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame];
    background.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    background.image = backgroundImage;
    [background sizeToFit];
    [backgroundImage release];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundView:background];
    [background release];
    [self.tableView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
    selectedOCData = nil;
    self.tableView.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
}
```

The line :

```
 UIImage* backgroundImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TableBg" ofType:@"png"]];
```

leaks 98% and the haviest backtrace is 240 kb. I attached a screenshot with instruments for this. Is there a problem not with the actual call of initWithContentsOfFile, but with the tableView which is not deallocated correctly?(My class is a tableViewController).

Thanks, 
Alex.
[image: instruments]

Comment: It's difficult to tell from just that code, but it looks basically correct. Since you're treating `tableView` as a class property, make sure you deallocate `tableView` in your `dealloc` method.
If you want more in-depth help, I'd suggest starting a new question.